# css navigation fixed width of the page

Tags: css

I have a navigation list

```
<div id='nav'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='index.php' id="home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='products.php' id="products">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href='sign up.php' id="signup">Sign up</a></li>
            <li><a href='cart.php' id="cart">Cart</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and I already make the style of the "a" elements by CSS, 25px tall and 100px wide and give the background colour,

```
#nav li a {
height: 25px;
width: 100px;
display: block;
text-align: center;
background-color:#FFE9BA;
}
```

but I still want the whole navigation span the width of the page, how can I do this? Thanks！

Comment: im not sure what you mean ... you want the #nav div to be as wide as whole page ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tHvdz/)?

Added the following CSS

```
#nav {
text-align: center;
background-color:#FFF9CA;
}


#nav li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works a little bit, and if I add `float:left;` in the `#nav li`

```
#nav li { display: inline-block; float:left;}
```

then looks does not change anything.

Without using `ul`, I changed to use `table` and it fix the problem, it looks easier for me.

Anyway, thanks for helping.